# Azure SQL Server JSON without DTU usage

Tags: sql-server, json, azure

I have a S0 Standard Azure SQL server where i would like to bring in 100GB of JSON data without smashing through my DTU allowance and getting charged a huge amount of money.  I have £20 GBP per month Azure credit from my Developer Program Benefit subscription.

Is there any way of attaching an uploaded MDB / LDB to an Azure SQL SaaS ?

Unless anyone else has suggestions on how to not break my DTU allowance i wanted to try importing the JSON in to a local install of SQL Server 2016 and then attaching the database file to the server so that it is pre-processed.

This will be a long upload and will incur costs for a new file storage so does anyone know if this will work or how i might do it once uploaded?

Any info on how to prevent DTU usage for a JSON upload would be appreciate.

Comment: well, you can import from bacpac, and uploading to blob storage won't cost you lots, its really cheap. Also, what do you mean by breaking the DTU allowance? When you hit one of the limits, queries just slow down, its not like you would get 5xx errors or something

Comment: Thanks, I needed to do more reading on DTUs obviously.  I thought of it as like prepaid minutes on a mobile phone.  I was assuming if i were to break the limit i would either be charged an extra fee.  I have to be careful as i created an artificial charging cap by reporting my credit card lost and intentionally not updating the details in Azure.

Comment: go for it, would however appreciate you actioning the part i removed from question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the actual answer to this question is - DTU aren't like prepaid resources, DTU are allocated according to your Plan and you use them like CPU\Memory\Disk "cycles". When you exceed DTU quota nothing "bad" happens, you are just throttled, so think of this a capacity limit, not a spending limit.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate the raw json file to Azure Storage and use the new json features of azure SQL. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/10/07/bulk-importing-json-files-into-sql-server/